# What is the difference between DbUpdateConcurrencyException and DbConcurrencyException?

Tags: c#, .net, exception

Maybe my search queries weren't very sophisticated, but I didn't managed to find the correct answer I am looking for.

I am working on a webapplication in .NET Core (MVVM) with quite some forms for CRUD-operations. I am in a learning curve, watched a couple of tutorials and read the documentation on MSDN, but I wasn't able to the right answer I am looking for. They all use them differently.

What's the **concrete** difference between `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` and `DbConcurrencyException`? And when do I need to use which exception in the try-catch-statements? (with respect to create, update and delete).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically speaking, the source of each exception is different.

[DbConcurrencyException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dbconcurrencyexception(v=vs.110).aspx) is thrown by a [DataAdapter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter(v=vs.110).aspx) using a pretty simple concurrency check. It compares the record affected but the SQL action to the records changed using the object model.

[DbUpdateConcurrencyException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbupdateconcurrencyexception(v=vs.113).aspx) is thrown by EntityFramework when you implement their [Optimistic Concurrency Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592904(v=vs.113).aspx).

Comment: Thanks for answering. So in terms of good practice, it would be better to use the `DbUpdateConcurrencyException`, since the other once doesn't meet the requirements for most forms (?)

Comment: If you are using EntityFramework you do need to use DbUpdateConcurrencyException.